# SQL: ограничение выборки

Tags: mysql

Не пойму как правильно составить `SQL`-запрос.

Задача: есть три (количество всегда меняется) `iid - (3, 4, 10),` и есть таблица с большим количеством строк.

`iid` это ид строки из другой таблицы
`uid` это ид юзера

так вот, у каждого юзера есть большое количество разных `iid` (одинаковых нет) - скрин выше

мне нужно взять те выше описанные `iid` (3, 4, 10) и достать всех юзеров (не больше 7) которые имеют эти `iid`

```
SELECT `uid`,`iid` FROM `interests` WHERE `iid` in(4,3,10)
```

так вытаскиваются все uid, а мне нужно только 7 uid на 1 iid.

Если честно, я даже не представляю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT `uid`,`iid` FROM `interests` WHERE `iid` in(4,3,10) LIMIT 7

Comment: Нет-нет, не то однозначно.

Comment: Не так?

    select iid, uid from (select a.iid, a.uid,
       @cnt := case when @iid = a.iid then @cnt+1 else 1 end cnt,
       @iid := a.iid iid1 
    from (select iid, uid 
       from interest where iid in (3, 4, 10) order by iid) a,
      (select @cnt := 0, @iid := NULL) b) c
    where cnt < 8;

Comment: Да, вроде работает! Не удалось проверить полностью. Пока нет необходимого количества информации в БД.

Comment: Расписать бы запрос, чтоб понял.

Comment: Не уверен, что там лишнего не наворочено. Самый внутренний select -- выборка нужных iid и сортировка по ним. Средний -- с помощью локальных переменных добавляется вспомогательное поле cnt от 1 до максимума -- номер в групее по iid. При несовпадении iid с предыдущим, @iid, @cnt устанавливается в 1, иначе -- @cnt+1. Ну и внешний -- убрать лишние поля и ограничить cnt < 8 (cnt <= 7)

Answer (score 1):

например, так (для краткости — выбор по три, а не по семь строк, для каждого из `iid in (3, 4, 10)`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17085/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (uid int, iid int);

insert into t values
   (1, 3)
  ,(1, 4)
  ,(1, 10)
  ,(2, 3)
  ,(2, 4)
  ,(2, 10)
  ,(3, 3)
  ,(3, 4)
  ,(3, 10)
  ,(4, 3)
  ,(4, 4)
  ,(4, 10)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
(select * from t where iid = 3 limit 3)
union
(select * from t where iid = 4 limit 3)
union
(select * from t where iid = 10 limit 3)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17085/4/0)**:

```
| uid | iid |
|-----|-----|
|   1 |   3 |
|   2 |   3 |
|   3 |   3 |
|   1 |   4 |
|   2 |   4 |
|   3 |   4 |
|   1 |  10 |
|   2 |  10 |
|   3 |  10 |
```