# Что значит символ @ в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Пример вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/176700/mysql-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

он же вот

```
select iid, uid from (select a.iid, a.uid,
   @cnt := case when @iid = a.iid then @cnt+1 else 1 end cnt,
   @iid := a.iid iid1 
from (select iid, uid 
   from interest where iid in (3, 4, 10) order by iid) a,
  (select @cnt := 0, @iid := NULL) b) c
where cnt < 8;
```

обьясните мне что значит знак @

```
@cnt
```

вижу несколько вложенных запросов, так вот эти переменные с знаком @cnt относятся как то к переменным без знака

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

Comment: А за @cnt и cnt -- извините. @cnt -- переменная, cnt -- поле внутреннего запроса select 

      @cnt := case when @iid = a.iid then @cnt+1 else 1 end cnt,

или 

      (@cnt := case when @iid = a.iid then @cnt+1 else 1 end) cnt,

для ясности.

Answer (score 3):

Символом **@** обозначаются локальные переменные в запросе.

То есть мы говорим что это переменная, и уже дальше мы используем её значение.

Answer (score 1):

И еще, локальные переменные объявляются с `DECLARE`(в процедурах) и обязательно задается тип переменной `(VARCHAR,INT,etc)`,а **@** обозначается глобальная переменная, то есть между процедурами можно использовать эти переменные,и плюс к этому у них конкретно не указывается тип данных,как и в пхп.